# Error running HR ADF Mobile sample

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, oracle-maf

I'm trying to run the HR sample app but I'm having the following error:

```
--sign iPhone Distribution: Gary Zamorano (BH36YRHH44) --embed /Users/garyzamorano/Proyectos/GRK_IPAD_profile_ad_hoc.mobileprovision
[01:45:13 PM] error: /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules --sign iPhone Distribution: Gary Zamorano (BH36YRHH44) --resource-rules=/var/folders/68/qtr2dz896bb410t36p_2bjwr0000gn/T/XVV6umKpQY/Payload/HR.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /var/folders/68/qtr2dz896bb410t36p_2bjwr0000gn/T/XVV6umKpQY/entitlements_plist4QFl794s /var/folders/68/qtr2dz896bb410t36p_2bjwr0000gn/T/XVV6umKpQY/Payload/HR.app failed with error 1. Output: Warning: usage of --preserve-metadata with option "resource-rules" (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)!
[01:45:13 PM] Warning: --resource-rules has been deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10!
[01:45:13 PM] Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [Warning: usage of --preserve-metadata with option "resource-rules" (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)!
[01:45:13 PM] Warning: --resource-rules has been deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10!
[01:45:13 PM] Command-line execution failed (Return code: 1)
[01:45:13 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[01:45:13 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[01:45:13 PM] Failed to package the XCode application.
[01:45:13 PM] Failed to build the iOS application bundle.
[01:45:13 PM] Deployment failed due to one or more errors returned by '/usr/bin/xcrun'.  The following is a summary of the returned error(s):
Command-line execution failed (Return code: 1)
error: /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules --sign iPhone Distribution: Gary Zamorano (BH36YRHH44) --resource-rules=/var/folders/68/qtr2dz896bb410t36p_2bjwr0000gn/T/XVV6umKpQY/Payload/HR.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /var/folders/68/qtr2dz896bb410t36p_2bjwr0000gn/T/XVV6umKpQY/entitlements_plist4QFl794s /var/folders/68/qtr2dz896bb410t36p_2bjwr0000gn/T/XVV6umKpQY/Payload/HR.app failed with error 1. Output: Warning: usage of --preserve-metadata with option "resource-rules" (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)!
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [Warning: usage of --preserve-metadata with option "resource-rules" (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)!
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Please specify which JDeveloper you use. And which XCode version you have.

Answer (score 0):

From this thread: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3611632?start=15&tstart=0

For those using Mac OS 10.9.5 or 10.10 (Yosemite), please download the latest MAF patch via Help > Check For Updates.  This should fix your codesign issues